# How to maintain 2 same repositories in different OSes?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-queue

I have a cloned Mercurial remote repo on Linux.

Some features I work on need to be tested on Windows also.

So, I cloned the same remote repo in both Linux and Windows.
They are the same repositories, which must have the **same changes** I make. The source code always must remain the same on both Windows and Linux. Just to test and debug, I'll need to work atop my Linux changes on Windows and vice-versa.

Can someone suggest a good workflow?

I  have basic experience with using Mercurial Queues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to push/pull directly from the Windows to the Linux repository and vice versa, assuming you have a network connection between the computers.

You can enter an abbreviation for the path of the other repository in your `~/.hgrc` or in each repository's `.hg/hgrc` in the `[paths]` section so that you don't always have to enter it in full.

Comment: Will it be easier if I copied my MQ patches from one repository to another?

Comment: That may be a matter of taste, but I found pushing MQ patches back and forth always a bit cumbersome. You can use `hg push\pull --mq`, but then you have to specify the remote patches repository (i.e., `...repopath/.hg/patches`) and have to do `hg qcommit` before each push or pull. Personally, I find it easier to just use normal revisions instead.

Comment: How do patch reviewers review a patch I send them? Do they manually edit their `.hg/patches/series` file, add copy the patch there and then `hg qpush patch_name` ?

Comment: Mercurial queues are not designed for that workflow; their normal purpose is to maintain purely local patches that are not meant for general consumption. If you really wish to set up a review process for patches through email, you want `hg bundle` or `hg export`. However, it is more common to put such unfinished work in a feature branch which is merged when review is complete.

Comment: I use this work flow (pulling from local repo running on a Linux box from from my Windows box) I also use hg serve to allow pulling from my linux box when I don't have a network share setup.